# Xamarin how to send picker value to a list

Tags: xamarin

Im trying to send picker values that the user has chosen to a list. The list should keep on adding what the user chooses and not delete the previous. Any tips on how to do this?

```
 private void MainPicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

             var product = MainPicker.Items[MainPicker.SelectedIndex];
             DisplayAlert(product, "Layer added to calculation list", "OK");

        }
 private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender,SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.SelectedItem == null)
           // if selected add to list?

        }
```

Comment: It depends what is your list to add  selected item & what have you have binded to `Picker`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your question is about adding a selected item from a picker to a list view which keeps on adding based on the picker selection.

You can do the below code as a public object in the class.

```
ObservableCollection<LayersClass> listProducts = new ObservableCollection<LayersClass>();
```

Then get the selected picker item. Assuming the output and collection object is of same type.

```
var product = MainPicker.Items[MainPicker.SelectedIndex];
if(null != product)
{
   LayersClass layer = new LayersClass();
   layer.Product = product;
   listProducts.Add(layer);
}
```

XAML changes for the list view - You need to add the ViewCell tag below the DataTemplate which has your listview item child

```
<ListView  
                  x:Name="productsListView"
                  HasUnevenRows="False" 
                  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                  BackgroundColor="White" >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Product}"></Label>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

I have added the ViewCell inside the DataTemplate tag.